# How I can invoke importing class in other class Python

Tags: python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import time
import getopt
import alsaaudio
import numpy
from time import sleep


    class A_weight():

        def __init__(self):
            skaler = 2.361E-14
            fix_cur = 0.20565360419770495
            A = []
            hPa = 4e-11
            card = 'default'
            array_float = numpy.dtype(float)
            stream = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, card)
            stream.setchannels(1)
            stream.setrate(48000)
            stream.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
            stream.setperiodsize(128)

       def A(f):
            return (12200**2*f**4/((f**2+20.6**2)*(f**2+12200**2)*numpy.sqrt(f**2+107.7**2)*numpy.sqrt(f**2+737.9**2)))+fix_cur

       def listen(self):
            glob_leq = 0
            liczba_ramek = 0
            index_ramek = 0
            while True:
                try:
                   l, data = stream.read()
                except IOError, e:
                   error_count += 1
                   print(" (%d) Error recording: %s" % (error_count, e))
                else:
                   if l==128:
                       decoded_block = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype='int16' )
                   else:
                    continue
                Y = numpy.fft.fft(decoded_block) # fft computing and normalization
                Aw = A(numpy.arange(20.,20000,(19980./len(Y))))
                Na = Aw*Y
                inverse = numpy.fft.ifft(Y)
                maks = 32768
                array_float = numpy.divide(inverse.real ,float( maks))
                array_float = array_float**2
                sum_array = numpy.sum(array_float, dtype=float)
                glob_leq = glob_leq + sum_array
                liczba_ramek += 1
                index_ramek += 1
                if index_ramek == 375:
                   index_ramek=0
                   cis_chwil = numpy.divide(glob_leq, liczba_ramek * 128)
                   leq =10*numpy.log10(numpy.divide(cis_chwil, hPa))
                   print (leq)
                   #A.append(leq)
                   #print(max(A))
A_weight().listen()
```

So i trying writing program compute sound pressure level with weighting A.
All work correct but when i want close may code in class I have problem. Because something wrong with invoke to importing class in this case is it alsaaudio. 
I get this feedback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rec_A.py", line 64, in <module>
A_weight().listen()
File "rec_A.py", line 37, in listen
l, data = stream.read()
NameError: global name 'stream' is not defined
```

Do you have any idea

Comment: ``stream`` is currently a local variable within ``__init__()`` - it cannot be accessed anywhere else.  You need to use ``self.stream`` instead, to make it an instance variable that can be accessed from other methods of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change each occurrence of `stream` to `self.stream`:

```
class A_weight():

    def __init__(self):
        skaler = 2.361E-14
        fix_cur = 0.20565360419770495
        A = []
        hPa = 4e-11
        card = 'default'
        array_float = numpy.dtype(float)
        self.stream = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, card)
        self.stream.setchannels(1)
        self.stream.setrate(48000)
        self.stream.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
        self.stream.setperiodsize(128)

    ...

    def listen(self):
        glob_leq = 0
        liczba_ramek = 0
        index_ramek = 0
        while True:
            try:
               l, data = self.stream.read()

    ...
```

This will make it an instance variable, and all other methods of that class (as long as they are passed the `self` argument) will have access to it through `self.stream`. See [this bit of documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) for more details on instance variables.

Also, this is merely an aesthetic point, but the convention in Python is to use upper camel case for class names, i.e., `AWeight` instead of `A_weight` - but this will not affect how your code runs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Everything work very well :)

Comment: @Bednar great! Don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: :) Yes I know but i don't can vote because my reputation is less than 15.